# arm6 is missing in my build settings

Tags: ios, architecture, arm, armv6

I am getting this error when i try to archive my project:

> warning: iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable is missing a required architecture.  At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv6 (-19033)
>   Unable to validate your application. - (null)

I have checked my build settings but i just don't see ARM6 in the options, only 7.

Any help will be appreciated.

Shni

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Manually add armv6 in 'PROJECT' by double clicking the armv7 bit, deleting what's there and adding armv6 and armv7.
[image: Editing PROJECT in Xcode to manually modify Standard (armv7)]

Comment: I had to adjust the setting "Valid architectures" to "armv6 armv7". After that it worked for me too!

Comment: I had the value $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) which displayed as armv7 (Standard).  Replaced it with two items [armv6, armv7].  Fixed!  Thanks Cirrostratus.

Comment: Well, it did work but only when i archive. when i build for debug i must range it back.

Comment: @shannoga did you make the change in your 'Target' instead of 'Project'?

Comment: After wasting my enire day I saw your post. And I can't say how happy I am. It was really worst day but you safe me and I was able to submit the application to the app store. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

- Set "Build Active Architecture Only" to NO;
- Change $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) to armv6 and armv7;
- Make changes in "PROJECT", not "TARGETS".

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding the armv6 architecture, I had to remove the armv7 entry from my apps info.plist "Required Device Capabilities" entry in order to get my app to run on my old iTouch.