# App not running on device (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, ios4, jailbreak

Today, m getting strange problem. My app is not running on device(Jailbreak). Earlier I have run other app on the device. Yesterday, I have formatted device, now application is not running on the iPhone - 4.2.1.
I have added all the required things like provisioning profile. I have also checked in apple developer site. that device is added to that portal. 
I have targeted my application to 4.2 as my device version is 4.2.1.
No error is coming when m trying to run the app. only it ends in “finished running app on iphone”.
M not getting where and what m missing..

Comment: Check the console, it's located on Organizer --> Devices. There you will see your device, click on the console and try to run the app, there will print any error.

Comment: Yes, its giving following error  :  unknown lockdownd[17] <Error>: 2ff68000 handle_connection: Could not receive USB message #6 from MDCrashReportTool. Killing connection

Comment: Search google about this error, or check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838154/xcode-4-2-cant-debug-ios-4-2-1-8c148)!, it may help you.

Comment: Thnx a lot guys..I have solved this, i was missing a very simple and important thing..armv6 has to be added in architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset the Simulator . Delete the Build File. And Restart the xCode. And Run the yor Project.I Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project and delete the build folder. Clean all the installed provision profile from device then restart Xcode. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Are you trying to debug app on iPhone device from Xcode, are you getting splash screen of your app or try to debug your app in simulator also. Plz try to debug other projects.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the Build File, Reset the Simulator , And Restart the xCode. And than run your project. and got output on device.